# Need to make a scrolling marquee type message in Powershell, but can't figure out the code

Tags: powershell, scrolling, marquee

I need to make a scrolling marquee type message to be displayed in a text box where the message is customizable and can be issued via Powershell script.  I've tried and tried to no avail as none...I've gotten as far as having it scroll in the output box, but can't seem to get it into a text box...help please!

`` $s=' '*80+(read-host)+' '*80;for(){write-host($s.Substring(($i=++$i%($s.length-80)),80)+"`r")-N -F R -B 0;sleep -m 99} ``

Comment: do you want this in a text console window or in a GUI?

Comment: GUI would be preferred...want to use it as an announcement system when things are down such as email or VPN.  I can still push scripts out to devices in these instances and would save a ton of helpdesk calls.

Comment: have you thot about doing this in a browser? that has scrolling text built in [for now]. lookee >>> <marquee>: The Marquee element - HTML: HyperText Markup Language | MDN — https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Comment: What did you search for? This is a common thing in console apps, client apps, and in web pages, with samples all over the web and on Youtube. A quick web search using your favorite search engine will give the details. ['powershell winform scrolling marquee'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%27powershell%20winform%20scrolling%20marquee%27&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=%27powershell%20winform%20scrolling%20marque%27&sc=0-37&sk=&cvid=20AC8BEE305C45DC9A9C5A9BFC91A8A0)

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comments and the search link I posted: first few hits:

> https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/weekend-scripter-using-windows-powershell-to-make-a-marquee

For a Winform - a C# option you can convert or use as-is:

> https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8ea152/marquee-a-text-in-C-Sharp-net-4-0-window-form-application

The code sample you posted is the same that was posted here:

> https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/58732/make-me-a-scrolling-marquee

All in all, it's just a matter of write text to the textbox, clearing that text, and writing it again. Again, and simple search for this use case would show you this.

> Retrieving Status Through PowerShell's Graphical Windows Form
>
> https://mcpmag.com/articles/2014/02/04/powershell-graphical-windows-form.aspx

```
Add-Type -assembly System.Windows.Forms
$form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

$path  = 'D:\Temp'
$Title = "Directory Usage Analysis: $Path"

$height = 100
$width  = 400
$color  = 'White'

$form1.Text            = $title
$form1.Height          = $height
$form1.Width           = $width
$form1.BackColor       = $color
$form1.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::FixedSingle


$label1        = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$label1.Text   = 'not started'
$label1.Left   = 5
$label1.Top    = 10
$label1.Width  = $width - 20
$label1.Height = 50
$label1.Font= 'Verdana'

$form1.controls.add($label1)
$form1.Show()  | 
out-null

$form1.Focus() | 
out-null


$label1.text = "Preparing to analyze $path"
$form1.Refresh()
start-sleep -Seconds 1

$top = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Directory

foreach ($folder in $top) 
{
    $label1.text = "Measuring size: $($folder.Name)"

    $form1.Refresh()

    start-sleep -Milliseconds 100

    $stats = Get-ChildItem -path $folder -Recurse -File |
    Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -Average

    [pscustomobject]@{
        Path   = $folder.Name
        Files  = $stats.count
        SizeKB = [math]::Round($stats.sum/1KB,2)
        Avg    = [math]::Round($stats.average,2)
    }
}

$form1.Close()
```

The above code can be easily tweaked a scrolling message, in a very similar way the directories shown are done. Just read in a message text, vs directories.